# Blackberry plugin for eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

As i am developing an where app where i need to integrate BBM in it. As per the following instructions of  [integrating BBM](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/blackberry-messenger.html), i followed the steps & downloaded [BB Plugin for Eclipse](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse). Here by default i got BB 7.1 SDK with that eclipse which i downloaded. Now i want to install BB 5.0 & BB 6.0 to that eclipse.

As per details i got from internet i followed the following steps of installing these SDK's
In eclipse
       Help --> Install New Software --> in Add Repository i gave name & location as

```
      Name --> Blackberry plugin
  Location --> http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java
```

But here i am getting **"could not find http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java"** .

So, can anyone help me with this how to install 5.0 & 6.0 to Eclipse as i downloaded from the above BB Plugin for Eclipse url........

Thanks in advance......

Comment: can i use this link in ADT eclipse ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this location instead. I am using Eclipse 3.6.1 and it works for me.

`http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java`

Comment: working on that dude, will let you know after successful installation & thanks for the URL.....

Comment: @mihirmehta Checked it - it works. You can't just *open* it. In the latest Eclipse versions you need to enter it to **Eclipse->Help->Install New Software->Work With** field and press the **Add** button..

Answer (score 0):

> **Use Eclipse to install the BlackBerry Java Plug-in.**

1. Choose `Help` > `Install New Software`.
2. Click `Add`.
3. For `Name`, type **BlackBerry Java Plug-in Update Site**.
4. For `Location`, type **http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/mac/java**.

> Mac: **http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/mac/java**
>
> Windows: **http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java**

1. Click `OK`.
2. Select `BlackBerry Java Plug-in` and at least one BlackBerry SDK. Choose the version of the BlackBerry SDK that is compatible with your intended target market.
3. Click `Next`.
4. Review the items being installed, and then click `Next`.
5. Review the license agreement, and then check `I accept the terms of the license agreement` if you agree.
6. Click `Finish` to begin the installation.
7. After the plug-in is updated, you'll be prompted to restart Eclipse.

Comment: This documentation appears to be from the official BB download page here: http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/download/