# Does Linux environment supports development of phonegap appliction for blackberry platforms

Tags: linux, cordova, blackberry

I am newbie of phonegap development. I have installed phonegap(cordova) and developed a sample application for android project and deployed to android devise successfully. My environment is "Linux(ubuntu 12.04)". Now I want to add blackberry platform for the sample phonegap application. What my question is

**Does Linux environment supports blackberry platfrom?**

**Can I use Blackberry plug-in for eclipse IDE in Linux Platfrom If Yes, How ?**

I have searched through google, they says blackberry webworks works only in windows and Mac OS. But I added Blackberry10 to cordova app, it worked but i was confused how to deploy the app to blackberry simulator/device.

Am I going in a wrong way. Can anyone please help on this. I was struggling from past one day on this.

Comment: check this http://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/requirements/ and this http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/overview_2006571_11.html

Comment: @Arvin: Means we need to use momentics IDE for blackberry10 in linux. Can't we use webworks IDE in Linux

Comment: @Arvin My another question we will deploy android application by installing .apk file in phonegap build, can we use some method like this to install it on blackberry? sorry if my question is dumb

Comment: i never used BB but there is plugin for ubuntu + eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491049/blackberry-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/first_app_1968215_11.html

Comment: @Arvin Thanks Arvin. I will check with them